# Build List with Attached Items

Tags: google-sheets, split, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

My cells look like this:

[image: What I have]

I want them to look like this with spacing between cells that need it to accommodate the repairs that were completed:

[image: What I would like]

If there is any other information that would help, I would be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(
 IF(D1:D="",,"×"&TO_TEXT(A1:A)&"♦"&B1:B&"♦"&C1:C&REPT("× ", 
 LEN(REGEXREPLACE(D1:D, "[^,]", )))),,9^9), "×")), "♦"), 
 QUERY(TRIM(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SPLIT(D1:D, ",")))), "where Col1 is not null", )})
```

[image]

---

### update 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(
 IF((D1:D="")*(A1:A=""),,"×"&TO_TEXT(A1:A)&"♦"&B1:B&"♦"&C1:C&REPT("× ", 
 LEN(REGEXREPLACE(D1:D, "[^,]", )))),,9^9), "×")), "♦"), 
 SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(TRIM(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SPLIT(IF((D:D="")*(A:A<>""),"¤",D1:D), ",")))), 
 "where Col1 is not null", ), "¤", )})
```

[image]

---

### update 2:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TO_TEXT(A1:A)&"×"&B1:B&"×"&C1:C&"×"&
 TRIM(SPLIT(IF((A1:A<>"")*(D1:D=""), "♥", D1:D), ","))), "×"), 
 "where Col4 is not null"), "♥", ))
```

[image]

#### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b82VrXSeYtOoKUesmCBPiAH98kCFxmNMh6Rl__qnl-o/edit#gid=0)

Comment: This worked pretty well but when a device doesn't have anything in its field like screen or battery yet as it hasn't been repaired yet, the entire entry for those items isn't displayed. Is there any way to print these lines without an entry in D as well?

Comment: @TJHarris answer updated

Comment: One last question, it seems when trying to pull this data, it's wanting to have all of the data repeated within it's cells where empty cells were inserted. Is it possible to copy cells A,B, and C when D was needed to be expanded down in cell I? Essentially, would it be possible for F1, G1, and H1 to be copied automatically to rows 2 and 3 and have this work for every other row that returns a blank cell to accommodate for the Cell D list expanded?

Comment: @TJHarris not sure what are you asking... can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with example of desired result?

Comment: What you did works perfectly the way I thought would work for reporting but I changed the output image of what I think Data Studio is going to need. Also, thank you for all of this. I've tried to look into your work and comprehending it is a bit beyond my scope right now.

Comment: Originally yes but the solution above with the first 3 columns repeated is needed instead of leaving them blank. I hadn't foreseen this issue before. I'm sorry for the miscommunication there.

Comment: @TJHarris see the 2nd update